# 2017 Dodge Journey

Tags: wiring

I recently bought a 2017 Dodge Journey SE 4 cyl that has a small 5"  radio in it, at first I was a proud owner of a lcd screen going from a 2002 Ford explorer to a 2017, but now I'm wondering if I can upgrade the Journey to an 8" touch screen that's in the 6cyl engines with heated seats, would it be a universal stock part ?

Answer (score 1):

If the opening in the dash is sufficiently large, then it will be a straight swap, assuming that the wiring is "standard". Most ICE have adaptor harnesses available to match the ICE to a vehicle.

If the opening is not large enough then different parts will be needed, sourcing the may be easy or challenging.